# User Input Validation - hasnext() while

Tags: java, iterator, java.util.scanner, do-while, boolean-logic

I have created a game that prints a random roll number between 1 & 10. The system then asks the user if they want to guess higher [1] or lower [2] for a second roll number. Based on their guess the system will print either "Draw!", "You guessed incorrectly." or "You guessed correctly.". The program then prompts the user as to whether they would like to restart the program (yes [y]) using a while loop.

However, now I am trying to validate the integer 'Guess' user input so that only [1]/[2] can be entered respectively. I am having difficulty setting these conditions using the hasNext() method using while loop. My program now doesn't continue after inserting the while loop upon correct or incorrect user entry.

See "//invalid user entry" block

Code:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    String replay = "y";
    Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
    while(replay.equals("y"))
    {

        //roll one
        int rNum1 = (int)(Math.random() * 11); //declare random roll one,  gives result between 1 and 10

        //print roll one
        System.out.println("You roll the 10-sided die."); 
        System.out.println("It lands on " + rNum1 + ".");
        System.out.println(); //space

        //User guess
        System.out.println("Will a second die roll higher or lower?");
        System.out.println("To guess higher enter [1], or to guess lower, enter [2].");

        //roll two
        int rNum2 = (int)(Math.random() * 11); //declare random roll two
        int guess = input.nextInt(); //user's guess / HiLo

        //invalid user entry
        while(!input.hasNextInt() || (guess != 1 && guess != 2)) 
        {
            System.out.println("Invalid entry"); // print incorrect guess entry input
            System.out.println("To guess higher enter [1], or to guess lower, enter [2].");
            input.next(); //reset scanner "input"
        }

        //print roll two
        System.out.println(); //space
        System.out.println("You roll the die again."); 
        System.out.println("It lands on " + rNum2 + ".");
        System.out.println(); //space


        if (guess == 1) //guessed higher
        {
            if (rNum1 == rNum2)
            {
                System.out.println("Draw!");
            }
            else if (rNum1 > rNum2)
            {
                System.out.println("You guessed wrongly.");
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("You guessed correctly!");
            }
        }

        if (guess == 2) //guessed lower
        {
            if (rNum1 == rNum2)
            {
                System.out.println("Draw!");
            }
            else if (rNum1 > rNum2)
            {
                System.out.println("You guessed correctly!");
            }
            else
            {
                System.out.println("You guessed wrongly.");
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Would you like to play again? Enter [y] for yes.");
        replay = input.nextLine();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just check the value of guess and if it doesn't satisfy the requirements ask again like this

```
    int guess = input.nextInt(); //user's guess / HiLo

    //invalid user entry
    while(guess != 1 && guess != 2) 
    {
        System.out.println("Invalid entry"); // print incorrect guess entry input
        System.out.println("To guess higher enter [1], or to guess lower, enter [2].");
        guess = input.nextInt(); //reset scanner "input"
    }
```

Something like this will work for anything entered by the user where we grab the entire line and see if it matches a digit, if it does then we parse the input into an integer and report if the value was not a 1 or 2 and continue to ask for input until the user enters the desired value of a 1 or 2

```
      int guess = 0;
      while(guess != 1 && guess != 2)
      {
          String inputFromUser = input.nextLine();
          if(inputFromUser.matches("\\d+"))
          {
              guess = Integer.parseInt(inputFromUser);
              if(guess != 1 && guess != 2)
                  System.out.println("Value must be either a 1 or 2");
          }
          else
              System.out.println("Invalid entry");
      }
```